# JavaScript pass ID result from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass an ID result from one function into another function.

So this is part of the JS calculator:

```
// Calculation JS Function   
var TPFund = FV(FPCharge, 12*YTRetire, -SCont, -EPen, 1)/(Math.pow(1+inf, YTRetire));

// ID element within JS
document.getElementById('MTPen').innerHTML = Number((TPFund).toFixed(0));
```

And I then call this into the page via this...

```
// Code within the HTML
<span id="MTPen" name="MTPen">xx</span>
```

...which gives me the calculation result.

I have a Google Chart function of which I have included an INPUT value 'EPen', which is simple and works as it's direct user input. Now being that the 'MTPen' is a calculated ID - I can't seem to call this ID into the following Google Chart function.

```
function drawChart() {

    // Called from INPUT value added by user **WORKS**  
    var VALA = parseFloat(document.getElementById("EPen").value)

    // Called from calculator function with ID result **NOT WORKING?**
    var VALB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("MTPen").value) 

    // Called from INPUT value added by user **WORKS**
    var VALC = parseFloat(document.getElementById("VAL3").value) 
    var VALD = parseFloat(document.getElementById("VAL4").value) 

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', document.getElementById("HEAD1").value],
      ['2004',  1000, 400, VALA],  
      ['2005',  1170, 460, VALB],
      ['2006',  660, 1120, VALC], 
      ['2007',  1030, 540, VALD] 
    ]);
```

I've been banging my head against the wall, any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of document.getElementById('MTPen').innerHTML, try using document.getElementById('MTPen').innerText. It may help.

Comment: This worked a real treat. 

By simply replacing the .innerHTML on the 'Calculation JS Function' to your suggested '.innerText' enabled me to pull through the 'MTPen' into my Google Chart function.

Thank you Sandip

Answer (score 0):

Use This:-

```
$('#btn1').on('tap', AddScore);
$('#trigger-link').on('tap', TriggerFunction);
```